# payment gateway is returning null in the session. please advice me

Tags: java, payment-gateway

I am using itz cash payment gateway.
 i am successfully paid the amount through payment gateway, after successful payment it should insert into data base, but in the response i got the null. please any one help me
Thanks in advance.

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

 if (userId != null)
        {                
            System.out.println("userId:" + userId);
            ff = userId.toString();                
            toCust = daoLogin.getUserInfoForCustomer(userId);

        }
```

Comment: In which line you are getting null?

Comment: it seems impossible to answer this question without further elaboration. what object does daoLogin point to?